# How do I make a JFoenix JFXToggleButton that looks like a ToggleButton not a switch?

Tags: javafx, toggle, togglebutton, jfoenix

Using the [JFoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) library, is there a way to have a toggle button that is a rectangle like the normal JavaFX `ToggleButton`?

The [`JFXToggleButton`](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/wiki/Toggle-Button) looks more like a switch—and that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To make something similar to the normal `ToggleButon`, you can use a lesser-known control in JFoenix called [`JFXToggleNode`](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/85674ebf0554c6e76df6c410f47d3f7d001e45e1/jfoenix/src/main/java/com/jfoenix/controls/JFXToggleNode.java).

As you can see in [the JFoenix Demo](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/wiki#trying-the-demo), this control often contains an icon.

[image: Toggle Icons]

But you can put *anything you want* in it. ***Why not a label?***

Being careful to not forget to include the `import` statements, just add the following to your FXML file by hand<sup>**§**</sup>.

```
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXToggleNode?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

...

<JFXToggleNode>
    <Label text="Boton Azul" />
</JFXToggleNode>
```

and add this rule to your stylesheet:

```
.jfx-toggle-node {
    /* This is the color once toggled on. */
    -jfx-toggle-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

**§**: Note that SceneBuilder doesn't support non-standard controls very well, yet, so though you *can't* drag and drop it, you *can* add it manually to the FXML file *just fine*.

[image: JFXToggleNode Animation]

Answer (score 0):

Here's my custom implementation of JFXToggleNode

Use any icon pack you want

```
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXToggleNode;
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.materialicons.MaterialIcon;
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.materialicons.MaterialIconView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;

public class ShowPasswordButton extends JFXToggleNode {
    private MaterialIconView visible = new MaterialIconView(MaterialIcon.VISIBILITY, "20");
    private MaterialIconView notVisible = new MaterialIconView(MaterialIcon.VISIBILITY_OFF, "20");

    public ShowPasswordButton() {
        super();
        this.init();
        this.setGraphic(visible);
        this.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                this.setGraphic(newValue ? notVisible : visible));
    }

    private void init() {
        visible.setFill(Paint.valueOf("#46a28d"));
        notVisible.setFill(Paint.valueOf("#46a28d"));
    }
}
```